# how to correctly setup ng-repeat with multiple received arrays

Tags: php, angularjs, ajax

I have problem with setting up ng-repeats in angular when I receive some arrays from php. Can anyone please explain it to me ? I would like to have one div for one position of array. Thanks for kind response and here's the code:

Angular

```
 <div ng-app="ReportRequest" ng-controller="InsertRequest" id="pos">
    <div ng-repeat="row in report.articles.rows" class="position articles">
       <p ng-bind="row"></p
    </div>
```

Angular ajax request(work's fine)

```
var RequestApp = angular.module('ReportRequest',[]);

RequestApp.controller('InsertRequest', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get("functions.php", {
}).then(function success(response) {
    $scope.report = response.data.rows;
  })
});
```

PHP (are there any mistakes ?)

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once  'db_connect.php';

function retrieveArticle($conn)
{

$prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM blog";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    //$num_of_rows = $result->num_rows;

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        //$id = $row['id'];
        $article[] = $row['article'];
    }


}

$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();

return $article;
}

$articles = array(retrieveArticle($conn));
$report = array('rows' => $articles);
echo json_encode($report);
```

Received data: (json format)
{"rows":[["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna.","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna.","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna."]]}

Comment: Do you actually have a missing `>` in your code? (`<p ng-bind="row"></p`)

Comment: @AlonEitan yes, thank you, but still that doesn't solve the problem

Comment: What about `ng-repeat="row in report"`? I don't see any `articles` key in PHP array, and you save the `rows` directly to `$scope.report`

Comment: @AlonEitan well i edited ng-repeat but I already have $scope.report = response.data.rows; in js and it won't show up, [edit] when there is just "row in report" it show's me this ["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi...

Comment: OK, so why do you do this `$articles = array(retrieveArticle($conn));`? You return an array, and saving the result into another array. Would it work if you comment-out that line and change `$report = array('rows' => $articles);` into `$report = array('rows' => retrieveArticle($conn));`?

Comment: @AlonEitan I tried it but it sill won't work and now it show's nothing

Comment: Last attempt to solve :) Try the following on PHP `echo json_encode(array('rows' => retrieveArticle($conn)));` (instead of the last 3 lines on your php code), change `ng-repeat="row in report.articles.rows"` to `ng-repeat="row in report"` and `<p ng-bind="row"></p` to `<p ng-bind="row"></p>` - Any change?

Comment: @AlonEitan ah no :/ i just noticed it shows this error in console - angular.min.js:123 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes], thanks for trying anyway :)

Comment: @AlonEitan I've found the error, I can't have exact two things in the array and that were the problem, thank you for helping and I'd like to give you some credit for it so if you can write it as answer I'll check it as correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your json example you provide, is an array of array. so you need to use two repeats in order to render those json i put an example with ul. Try out. This work for me.

**CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.report = {
  "rows": [
    [
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna.",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna.",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque hendrerit nec nulla at pretium. Suspendisse viverra tempus malesuada. In at imperdiet ipsum, eu ornare mi. Etiam eget massa ac est dapibus aliquam. Donec pharetra vehicula libero vulputate tristique. Nullam quam est, ultricies et varius pulvinar, hendrerit rhoncus ex. Integer urna leo, pellentesque non sapien ut, scelerisque imperdiet magna."
    ]
  ]
```

}

**HTML**

```
   <ul ng-repeat="item in report.rows" class="position articles">
       <li>{{$index}}
       <ul>
         <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in item track by $index">
         {{$index + '-'+value}}
       </li>
       </ul>
    </ul>
```